# What is the length of a PHP session id string?

Tags: php, mysql, session, sessionid

I'm making a table in a MySQL database to save some session data, including `session_id`. What should be the length of the `VARCHAR` to store the `session_id` string?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Depends on [session.hash_function](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function) and [session.hash_bits_per_character](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-bits-per-character).

Check out the [session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) page for more info.

> The higher you set session.hash_bits_per_character the shorter your
> session_id will become by using more bits per character. The possible
> values are 4, 5, or 6.
>
> When using sha-1 for hashing (by setting
> ini_set('session.hash_function', 1) the following session string
> lengths are produced by the three session.hash_bits_per_character
> settings:
>
> 4 - 40 character string
>
> 5 - 32 character string
>
> 6 - 27 character string

Comment: So 40 character is a secure set, and if I want to save some bytes, I must check the php config, right?

Comment: Check php.ini to see what the settings are. 40 characters is the result of SHA-1 hash function and 4 bits per character. You can do `echo strlen(session_id());` to see the length and make your database field accordingly.

Comment: For reference, the session_id length will also be 32 if you use the MD5 hash function and 4 hash bits per character. That made me tear my hair out for a few hours today.

Comment: @GustavoPinent The number of characters has no security implications, only the hash function with its inherent hash size. How you encode that hash is just a matter of what serializations the transport or storage systems require. Theoretically, you could encode a SHA1 in just 20 bytes with a simple bitfield. Unfortunately, cookies and URIs (common transports) support only characters, and depending on which charset and character encoding you can use you'll have serialization overhead; double with 4 bits/char (implied here is that characters are 8 bits long -- the other 4 bits are wasted).

Comment: As of PHP 7.1.0, there is [`session.sid_length`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.sid-length) instead of `session.hash_function` and `session.hash_bits_per_character`.

Answer (score 35):

@sachleen answer isn't full.
More detailed info about session id length is described [here](http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=88685).

Summary:

```
128-bit digest (MD5)  
4 bits/char: 32 char SID    
5 bits/char: 26 char SID    
6 bits/char: 22 char SID

160-bit digest (SHA-1)
4 bits/char: 40 char SID    
5 bits/char: 32 char SID    
6 bits/char: 27 char SID
```

And sample regex to check session id:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,-]{22,40}$/', $sessionId)
```

Comment: Excellent answer, the missing piece of a puzzle for me.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on these configuration settings:
**[session.hash_function](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function)** and **[session.hash_bits_per_character](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-bits-per-character)**

Shorter session ID lengths have the higher chance of collision, but this also depends a lot on the ID generation algorithm. Given the default settings, the length of the session ID should be appropriate for most applications. For higher-security implementations, you may consider looking into how PHP generates its session IDs and check whether it's cryptographically secure. If it isn't, then you should roll your own algorithm with a cryptographically secure source of randomness.

Comment: The chance of collision is entirely determined by hash function, entropy used, and volume of traffic.  Using a more secure hashing function will produce a larger session ID string, so if that's what you meant by shorter session ID lengths having a higher chance of collision, then you're correct, but shortening that length by using a higher bit depth per character will have no effect.

Comment: Is 128 characters long session id an overkill for generic web application?

Answer (score 1):

By the regular php installation length is always 26 (exmp: psprdaccghmmre1oo2eg0tnpe6)

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 7.1 if using session_create_id() the default session id length is 32 characters, however a user can change this default in php.ini

See the php.ini setting [session.sid_length](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.sid-length)