# How to select a random record from database only once

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a PHP page which selects a random record from MySQL database (a string, which will be used as a unique "token"). I want to select this random record only once and never again afterwards.

In order to do so, I add an extra field to the table (named 'numberfield', containing number `0`), which is incremented at the moment the specific record has been selected. This way, only records with the value of `0` in the numberfield table field can be selected. As soon as the random record has been selected the numberfield field is incremented to `1` and can not be selected anymore. I'm thinking about using the following PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT token FROM table WHERE numberfield < **1** ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1");

if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET numberfield=numberfield+1 WHERE token=" + $row[0] + "");
```

Will this be the right way to do it ? Any thoughts ?

Furthermore, I want to **avoid a different random record is selected** at page refresh. What will be the right and most simple way to keep the "token" in cache ? For example, is it possible to keep the "token" in a session which will not be overwritten during page refresh,  or do I have to use other techniques like Ajax etc. Your help and comment is highly appreciated !

Comment: How big is your table? If it will get pretty big, you may want to consider not using `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should stop using `mysql_` functions as they are deprecated.
2. You should avoid using `ORDER BY RAND()` in larger tables because of overhead incurred from seeking a random number.
3. To accomplish a `SELECT ... UPDATE` you would need some sort of locking. There is a slim chance that a row could be *randomly* selected twice. This can be prevented using a stored procedure.
4. You can just use the session id generated by PHP or a part of it. [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138670/how-unique-is-the-php-session-id) talks about how unique a session id is and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240936/679449) discusses the varying lengths.
5. You can alternatively create a random string on the PHP side which would save overhead from connecting to the database.